# How can I get Margin-left pixel, when I set the Margin to be auto

Tags: javascript, html

How can I get Margin-left pixel, when I set the Margin to be auto in HTML?
eg: HTML:`<img class="image_main" src="....." style="margin:auto;">`
i have no idea to do that.

thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

think about the property: offsetLeft.